# iptables, setting DSCP for DHCP?

Tags: iptables, dhcp

I'm trying to set the DSCP bits on DHCP packets. Although the below works fine for udp, the packet is always sent with DSCP of 16. Any ideas?

```
 iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p udp -j DSCP --set-dscp 1
 iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DSCP --set-dscp 1
 iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -j DSCP --set-dscp 1
 iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p udp -j DSCP --set-dscp 1
```

I'm using dhclient - I don't see any option there to set it either.

Looks like dhclient hard codes it here, fyi:

```
void assemble_udp_ip_header (interface, buf, bufix,
                             from, to, port, data, len)
        struct interface_info *interface;
        unsigned char *buf;
        unsigned *bufix;
        u_int32_t from;
        u_int32_t to;
        u_int32_t port;
        unsigned char *data;
        unsigned len;
{
        struct ip ip;
        struct udphdr udp;

        memset (&ip, 0, sizeof ip);

        /* Fill out the IP header */
        IP_V_SET (&ip, 4);
        IP_HL_SET (&ip, 20);
        ip.ip_tos = IPTOS_LOWDELAY;
```

Comment: Seems that iptables does not work with dhcp at all. Even a simple DROP rule for all UDP, fails to catch DHCP but catches all other UDP traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DHCP cannot be caught with iptables as it uses RAW sockets that bypass the entire netfilter mechanism. There are some sources that report this here:

http://louwrentius.com/why-filtering-dhcp-traffic-is-not-always-possible-with-iptables.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/297383/unable-to-block-dhcp-and-other-traffic-on-input-chain